# Attach() -> object not found error (R2Jags)

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

I am using the R2Jags package.

I first obtain the model as follows:

```
jags.data = list("Y"=y, "N"=N, Y1=y[1], C=x1)
# The parameters that we are monitoring (must monitor at least 1)
jags.params=c("sd.q","sd.r","Y", "X1", "X2")
model.loc=("ss_model.txt")
mod_ss = jags(jags.data, parameters.to.save=jags.params, model.file=model.loc, n.chains = 3, 
              n.burnin=5000, n.thin=1, n.iter=10000, DIC=TRUE)
```

But then when I use the following to get the posterior valeus of X1:

```
attach(mod_ss)
X1
```

I get:

> Error: object 'X1' not found

My question: how come and what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the instant downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

It seems that in the new version of R2Jags the correct function to call is:

```
attach.jags(mod_ss, overwrite=TRUE)
```

[So `attach.jags` instead of `attach()`]